# More "named" colours for matplotlib before colours get recycled?

Tags: matplotlib

As I plot more curves using matplotlib, I see the curves/lines use the following colours and cycle around:

- b
- g
- r
- c
- m
- y
- k

Can I *cycle* throughout more colours beyond just those 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib`'s `Cycler` objects to interact with an underlying color-changing machinery. By creating your own cycler of desired length, you can make the turnaround as large as you want.

Here's how you can customize a color cycler to taste:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
food_colors = plt.cycler('color', ['tomato', 'olive', 'chocolate',
                                   'salmon', 'plum', 'lime'])
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=food_colors)
```

The snippet above sets the default color cycle to `food_colors`. Now all the newly drawn plots should be cycling through the six colors above.

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(20):
    x, y, s = np.random.normal(10, 3, size=3)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'o', ms=s*6, alpha=0.6)
plt.show()
```

[image: circles]

Note that if you want to change the color cycle for a given axis only, you can use `ax.set_prop_cycle(food_colors)` instead of changing `rcParams`.

Comment: Thank you! I have a question: I see that new colour names are defined, but I fail to see where their values are defined. For example, what colour is *tomato*?

Comment: I pulled the named colors from [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html), but of course you can specify the colors in more generic fashion. For instance, html hex strings like '#7fcdbb' are okay to use too.